# INSERT rows by Comparing Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables like this:

```
ID     Name     Value
----------------------
1      Book1    A
2      Book2    B
3      Book3    C

Name
----------------------
Book4
Book5
```

I'm trying to write query to insert rows in the first table so it becomes:

```
ID     Name     Value
----------------------
1      Book1    A
2      Book2    B
3      Book3    C
1      Book4    NULL
2      Book4    NULL
3      Book4    NULL
1      Book5    NULL
2      Book5    NULL
3      Book5    NULL
```

I can't get it to work with this query:

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        b.Name,
        a.Value
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT Name FROM table2) b ON a.Name = b.Name
```

I also tried CROSS JOIN but still couldn't quite get it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You want insert rows or create that query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case I will name `TableA` your first table and `TableB` the one with only names. But next time try to provide some meaningfull names.

```
 INSERT INTO TableA
 SELECT A.ID, B.Name, Null
 FROM 
     (
     SELECT DISTINCT ID
     FROM TableA
     ) A, TableB B
```

Comment: Carlos, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, your query returns rows with IDs from TableA, Names from Table B and NULLs for value but Book1, Book2, Book3 with their respective values are not selected

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. Your query should work. Up voted.